# ajaxfileupload issue with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on uploading an image asynchronously and for that I got [this good tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/). I read it all and tried to remove the model which I don't need and make it according to my needs, but when I run that I get no error and the file is not uploaded either.

I put one echo in the controller upload function, but I don't get the echo string either, even though I put the full path in the ajaxfileupload [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator).

Here is my view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo site_url()?>public/assets/js/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#upload_file').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajaxFileUpload({
                        url          : 'upload2/upload_file',
                        secureuri    :  false,
                        fileElementId: 'userfile',
                        dataType     : 'json',
                        data         : {
                                           'title': $('#title').val()
                                       },
                        success : function (data, status)
                        {
                            if(data.status != 'error')
                            {
                                $('#files').html('<p>Reloading files...</p>');
                                refresh_files();
                                $('#title').val('');
                            }
                            alert(data.msg);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
          <h1>Upload File</h1>
          <form method="post" action="" id="upload_file">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" />

          <label for="userfile">File</label>
          <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="20" />

          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
          </form>
          <h2>Files</h2>
          <div id="files"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my controller is this:

```
<?php
    class Upload2 extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->helper('url');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('upload');
        }
        public function upload_file()
        {
            /* It's not even showing me this echo and the path is
               OK too, and even I put the whole path but no result. */

            echo "in upload_file";
            $status = "";
            $msg = "";
            $file_element_name = 'userfile';

            if (empty($_POST['title']))
            {
                $status = "error";
                $msg = "Please enter a title";
            }

            if ($status != "error")
            {
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
                $config['max_size']  = 1024 * 8;
                $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file_element_name))
                {
                    $status = 'error';
                    $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
                }
                else
                {
                    $data = $this->upload->data();
                    $file_id = $this->files_model->insert_file($data['file_name'], $_POST['title']);
                    if($file_id)
                    {
                        $status = "success";
                        $msg = "File successfully uploaded";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unlink($data['full_path']);
                        $status = "error";
                        $msg = "Something went wrong when saving the file, please try again.";
                    }
                }
                @unlink($_FILES[$file_element_name]);
            }
            echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to give full URL. You cannot access like this

Comment: i have even given the full url but no luck

Comment: The url may not be full but it must start with slash / ..
Do you get 404 or other http_code on request?

Comment: check the response in Firebug..

Comment: no i dont get the 404 error , browser show me the processing but nothing happen and console in furebug show me nothing not even post sending request

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: you did not put semi column(;) `<?php echo site_url()?>` here

Comment: but script is loaded and i can see this in firebug

Answer (score 0):

This is doable without any plugins or external scripts. You need your file upload element, an iFrame to return the data to and a simple Ajax script.

File upload element:

```
echo '<input type="file" name="prodImageUpload"
id="prodImageUpload" onchange="return ajaxFileUpload(this);"/>'
```

iFrame:

```
<iframe name="upload_iframe" id="upload_iframe" style="display:block;width:720px;"></iframe>
```

JavaScript script:

```
function ajaxFileUpload(upload_field)
{
    var re_text = /\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.png/i;
    var filename = upload_field.value;
    var imagename = filename.replace("C:\\fakepath\\","");
    if (filename.search(re_text) == -1)
    {
        alert("File must be an image");
        upload_field.form.reset();
        return false;
    }
    upload_field.form.action = "addProductImage";
    upload_field.form.target = "upload_iframe";
    upload_field.form.submit();
    upload_field.form.action = "";
    upload_field.form.target = "";
    return true;
}
```

In the controller for mine I have a custom upload, but that's irrelevant. All you need to do is pass the upload the control name and final path. I echo back errors if there are any or the file name and size if it works which prints to the iFrame. It is dead simple and works fine.

Comment: i tried ur way , i putt the input type file and iframe inside the form and putt the js script too , but i get this error
TypeError: upload_field.form.submit is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

upload_field.form.submit();

Comment: Are they inside a form? That was just the control itself, it still needs to be inside a form with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: yes they are inside a form and it has encrypt="multipart/form-data" too

Comment: and your form field looks like mine with the return onchange="return ajaxFileUpload(this);? There's no reason I can think of that it would return that error if you have exactly what I have above.